# $http.get Angular, проблема с получением данных из application/json rest api

Tags: json, angularjs, http, get, rest

Подскажите, пож, где собака зарыта?

Есть такой пример вызова $http.get на Ангуларе
HTML:

```
<body ng-app="httptest">
  <div ng-controller="getjson">
    <pre>
      <div>{{data}}</div>
    </pre>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("httptest", []);

app.controller("getjson", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVEwdw.js").
  success(function(res) {
    $scope.data = res;
  });
}]);
```

(http://codepen.io/stoxa/pen/pyORVj?editors=1111)

со ссылкой http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVEwdw.js,

возвращающей джсонину -

```
[{"nama":"Maria Belen","alamat":"Spanyol","pictures":["small.png","medium.png","big.png"]},{"nama":"Betty La Fea","alamat":"Spanyol","pictures":["small.png","medium.png","big.png"]}] - Работает
```

со ссылкой http://www.mocky.io/v2/571e719c0f00008e1b127cce, возвращаюещеё эту же джсонину - не работает..

пробовал и втулить в хедеры content-type. Результат тот же(

Comment: таки смотрите ошибку в консоли браузера

Comment: Смотрю в консоле кодпена, ошибок нет

Comment: слишком много ссылок в вопросе, и слишком мало кода. Вставьте код который вы используете и который не работает, непосредственно в вопрос

Comment: На всякий случай - возвращать json в виде массива в некоторых случаях небезопасно (он становится валидным js кодом, в отличии от json представляющего объект {} )

Answer (score 1):

Попробовал ваш код, в консоль вывалилось:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mocky.io/v2/571e719c0f00008e1b127cce. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Похоже проблема с cross-domain.

Заголовки в ответ на preflight options от mocky.io:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Cowboy
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 08:05:56 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

Нет необходимого заголовка Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Соответственно браузер пресекает дальнейшее получение данных.

Если действительно нужно работать именно с mocky.io, попробуйте JSONP, который там же предлагается. Для него нет ограничений по cross-domain.

Answer (score 0):

Код работает - а вот mocky.io почему-то возвращает пустой ответ. Учитесь пользоваться инструментами разработчика в вашем браузере.

Comment: Да, в этом и вопрос - почему не возвращает? Я смотрю в сторону хедеров, чарсетов. Но у меня не получилось добится возврата данных со всевозможными комбинациями конфигов в хедере

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module("httptest", []);

app.controller("getjson", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
  var url = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/571e719c0f00008e1b127cce" + "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
  $http({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",method: 'jsonp',url:url,headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
    .success(function(data) {
    if (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    }
  });
}]);
```